# three.js Export 3D scene to 2D DXF Views

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Does anyone have any example of exporting a 3D THREE.js scene to a 2D dxf? I can traverse my scene, get all of the faces of my objects, then vertices of these faces, and use them to create a DXF file right now by drawing lines between the dots. And by only using the x/y, x/z, z,y values of the vertices I can create my Front, Right, and Top views. My problem is when it is drawing lines between the vertices of the faces I am drawing all of the triangles that make up the faces, which leaves me with an overwhelming number of extra lines in my 2D views, especially on round surfaces.

Comment: have you tried using the svg renderer of THREE? Ex: http://threejs.org/examples/svg_sandbox.html

Comment: I was curious about that...I'll do some digging on it and see if I can get it to do what i'm looking for. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: tried playing around with the SVGRenderer and seem to be getting the same results, all of the edges of each triangle are still drawn in the svg file...I've tried ortho and perspective cameras as well. ortho helps with cube shaped objects, but cylinders have a ton of edges drawn when looking at them from the side.